# How to immediately turn WS2812 LED strip on after power on?

Tags: raspberry-pi, led-strip, ws2812b

I built a table lamp with a 1m WS2812 LED strip controlled by a RPI Zero W. It has a decent power supply that outputs 5V directly to the LED strip and also powers the RPI. The RPI takes approximately 25 secs to boot on power up and after that it sets the LED strip. This is way too long. How can I make the LED strip start immediately as it receives power and then let the RPI take over?

Comment: It looks like the data sheet permits a 50% duty cycle 800kHz square wave to be read as 'all ones', which *may* turn all the LEDs on if generated from, let's say, a 1.6MHz 555 and an HC74. I haven't looked further into the data sheet to see whether any sort of framing is required to make the data actually light the LEDs, but it's something to think about or experiment with.

Comment: 25s sounds like an eternity to boot an embedded device. Maybe simply have a script that turns on the strip **early** in the boot process rather than at the very end, if this is what you want?

Answer (score 3):

The WS2812 LEDs are turned on by instruction data shifted through each LED chip. This is explained well in the [WS2812 datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812.pdf). There is no simple "pull the data line high for a second and they'll all come on" technique. There *is* a reset command which is rather easy and that is to hold the data line low for 50 μs and all the LEDs will turn off.

To do what you want would require another microcontroller to send out the light-on commands while the Pi powers up. You would then need to figure out some way of switching to the Pi when the application is running.

Comment: no switching between the microcontroller and the RPi would be required ... simply make the microcontroller accept commands from the RPi

Comment: That might work. It would need to pass through the Pi commands with low jitter.

Comment: Following @jsotola good suggestion, the MCU wouldn't introduce jitter, just slightly variable latency. It wouldn't have anything else to do except wait for Pi message bytes then immediately generate WS2812 data.